# Get value of appended textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

i append a textarea with a button

```
$(".mydiv").append("<textarea id='myTextarea'></textarea><div class='sendReply btn btn-default'>my button</div>");
```

After that , i'm writing new texts into textarea and trying to get new writed value inside from textarea with this on click function ;

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.sendReply', function () {
  var myNewText =  $("#myTextarea").val();
    console.log(myNewText);
  });
```

But it says that this an "empty string" , if i add text area with a value like `<textarea id="myTextarea">some text</textarea>` my fucntion works and gives me "some text" but if i edit textarea and click sendReply button (my on click function), it is still gives me "some text" , it don't change

How can i get edited textarea value after apppend a textarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You have an `.` in `.sendReply` while appending the HTML</s>

You just need to remove `.` from `.sendReply`

*Use*

```
<div class='sendReply btn btn-default'>my button</div>"
```

As you are using Event delegation your jQuery will work.

**As you are adding textarea with same ID multiple times?** `$("#myTextarea").val()` will always show value of first textarea with id *myTextarea*. You can use a common class and then use [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to select the textarea

See example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.sendReply', function() {
    var myNewText = $(this).prev(".myTextarea").val();
    alert(myNewText);
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $(".mydiv").append("<textarea class='myTextarea'>some text</textarea><div class='sendReply btn btn-default'>my button</div>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mydiv'></div>
```

Comment: thank you but actually in my real code it is true , i edited question , i sad that if i add text area with a value like <textarea id="myTextarea">some text</textarea> my fucntion works so  button is working :)

Comment: @OsmanErdi, There is nothing wrong in code, Problem must be some were else. Are you adding textarea with same ID multiple times? If thats the case `$("#myTextarea").val()` will always show value of first textarea with id _myTextarea_

Comment: okay but you should add textareas with append function , after that you should try to get values

Comment: @OsmanErdi, Run code snippet I have added 5 textarea in example.

Comment: thank you very much i can fix my codes in project now , this is what i want to do , thank you , i think it'll be very usefull example for everone

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$(".mydiv").append("<textarea id='myTextarea'></textarea><div class='sendReply btn btn-default'>my button</div>");
```

then

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.sendReply', function () {
  var myNewText =  $("#myTextarea").val();
    console.log(myNewText);
  });
```

dont use dot(.) for the classname..

Comment: typo missing a `.` in your class selector

Comment: i changed it , still i cant get new edited value i will add jsfiddle , thank you

Comment: Yup please put your code in JsFiddle , it will be easy for us

Answer (score 1):

Instead using div .. use some standard to code up  .. you can make it has button .. here is the code

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>

$(".mydiv").append("<textarea id='myTextarea'></textarea><input type='button' class='sendReply btn btn-default' value='my button'></input>");
jQuery(document).on('click','.sendReply', function () {
  var myNewText =  $("#myTextarea").val();
    console.log(myNewText);
    alert(myNewText);
  });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/utq0pc8f/2/)**

Comment: ya there is nothing wrong , but its way of coding,,