# not able to get the appended textearea value

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, append

How can I get the appended Textarea value?

**tried this:** [get-appended-textare-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716892/get-value-of-appended-textarea) but didn't work

HTML Code:

```
<div class="request-detail" style="padding-right:10px" ></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var str = '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 futura_md_btmedium padding0 hidden reason"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 padding0">Reason</div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 padding0"><textarea placeholder="Reason to reject the request" style="padding-left:10px;height: 65px;" id="rcon-'+data1.request_id+'" rows="3" cols="5" class="reason-content form-control theme-input theme-input-padding theme-textarea"></textarea><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-right padding0"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 text-left req-msg padding0"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-right padding0"><a class="btn-default add-tour-img reject-myrequest" id="'+data1.request_id+'" href="javascript:;">Send</a></div></div></div></div>'
$('.request-detail').append(str);

$(document).on("click", '.reject-myrequest', function() {
var original_val = this.id;
var reason = $("#rcon-"+original_val).val(); // this returns always empty!
});
```

Comment: you tried to fill out value ? like :
      var reason = $("#rcon-"+original_val).val("Test Data");

Comment: @Alex this is printing something like this: Object[textarea#rcon.reason-content.form-control.theme-input.theme-input-padding.theme-textarea]

Comment: can you check what value `data1.request_id`  contains?

Comment: i mean pathik , you are adding function : val() without adding any value. so want to confirm that you filled value ? and Id should be correct at that time.

Comment: @DharaParmar it is interger val

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy You are wrong, `.val()` is the correct way to access `<textarea>` content with jQuery.

Comment: @kb. Yeah that's right. Got confused a bit.

Comment: @DharaParmar data1.request_id contains an integer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what `data1.request_id` contains,  I have set static value 1 as `data1.request_id` ans its working fine, so there should be some issue in `data1.request_id`.

```js
var test = 29;
var str = '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 futura_md_btmedium padding0 hidden reason"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 padding0">Reason</div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 padding0"><textarea placeholder="Reason to reject the request" style="padding-left:10px;height: 65px;" id="rcon-'+test+'" rows="3" cols="5" class="reason-content form-control theme-input theme-input-padding theme-textarea"></textarea><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-right padding0"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 text-left req-msg padding0"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-right padding0"><a class="btn-default add-tour-img reject-myrequest" id="'+test+'" href="javascript:;">Send</a></div></div></div></div>'
$('.request-detail').append(str);

$(document).on("click", '.reject-myrequest', function() {
var original_val = this.id;
var reason = $("#rcon-"+original_val).val(); // this returns always empty!
  alert(reason);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="request-detail" style="padding-right:10px" ></div>
```

Comment: data1.request_id contains an integer value

Comment: in that case it should work because in above example I have set test=1 (integer) and try to run script, it is working - can you show any error in console?

Comment: @PathikVejani I think there is not error, but then it should execute

Comment: I am appending whole string, so that it is not getting value? is it?

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/cd471d4a853249c785a56044b3ccf85e.png
see above screenshot. i am getting `data1.request_id`

Comment: no no..its not the case...can you show me text area and send button html togather in screen shot?

Comment: Ok let me try to take screenshot

Comment: let me clear that textarea and send button are in bootbox

Comment: ok is click event is working?? or even its not going in click event?

Comment: i cant see any mistake now here..it should work dude

Comment: You can `$.trim(this.id)`  which fetching id, so it remove spaces

Comment: let me try this too

Comment: and also plase make sure, ID is not duplicating - id should be unique for each element...

Comment: there was some duplicate id issue, thank you for helping me!